# Specifying sub-fields allowed in GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

Is it possible to specify the subfields allowed for a GraphQL Schema. For example I have this schema:

```
type User {
  username: String!
  mostPersonalSecretEver: String!
}

type Location {
  name: String!
  owner: User!
}
```

But I want to specify the only field you actually have access to is username. Is there a way to specify this in the schema? I'm guessing not, instead I have done this:

```
type User {
  username: String!
  mostPersonalSecretEver: String!
}

type SanitizedUser {
  username: String!
}

type Location {
  name: String!
  owner: SanitizedUser!
}
```

I'm just asking if there is a way I can't find to make a schema specify the fields available like this:

```
type Location {
  name: String!
  owner: User('username')!
}
```